# Russian equivalent for "looking forward to"

Tags: выражения, phrase

Probably this is related to questions such as [this one](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/23/3538)

> [...] Russians prefer to hint at their feelings instead of describing them.
>   Instead of saying they're excited about new job, they'll say the job is friggin' awesome.

For instance

> I'm looking forward to this meeting

might be expressed somehow like

> Будет [...] встреча

where the brackets can contain a positive adjectiv of ones choice

However, is there a phrase which is

- more close to the english `looking forward to`
- and used quite commonly

Comment: "С нетерпением жду встречи", "жду не дождусь встречи".

Comment: @Artemix "C нетерпением жду встречи", наверное, ближе.  Однако есть также фраза "I can hardly wait...", which translates literally "Жду - не дождусь встречи".

Comment: НЕ дословно, но зато менее неуклюже: До скорой встречи

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Буквальный перевод "I'm looking forward to this meeting", который можно было бы найти в словаре скорее всего такой:

> Я с нетерпением ожидаю этой встречи *(или собрания)*

Но здесь много "лишних" или "редких" слов: "Я", "ожидаю", "этой", которые использованы для того чтобы максимально приблизить все оттенки смысла русской фразы к английскому. Обычно говорят проще:

> С нетерпением жду встречи
>
> Очень жду встречи

Чтобы "спрятать" свое эмоциональное отношение к будущему событию, достаточно сказать "жду встречи". Но если встреча предполагается с каким-то близким человеком, то скорее всего это будет:

> Жду нашей встречи

Но в этом случае возникает вопрос - насколько уместно скрывать свое эмоциональное отношение к этому событию.

Answer (score 0):

1. предвкушать что-либо (~~ like foretaste)
2. ожидать чего-либо с удовольствием/нетерпением (~~ wait impatiently)